# Importing Microsoft Access file into SQL Server?

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2012

I tried to import a Microsoft Access file into SQL Server 2012.

Error:

> Copying to [dbo].[Placements] (Error)
>
> Messages
>
> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with Destination - Placements.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[LastTimeDate] on Destination - Placements.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - Placements.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907A occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Placements.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Placements" (97) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (110). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Placements returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Comment: What were the steps you took to try to "import" this access file into sql server?

Comment: Check the [LastTimeDate] column in the Access table to see if it contains any dates prior to January 1, 1753. If so, then you'll either have to fix those dates (if they are incorrect) our you'll have to tweak the column type mapping during the import to create a `datetime2` column (instead of a `datetime` column) in the SQL Server table.

Comment: I tried to change the data type . but it Prompts  :  "MS Access cant change the data type ; there is not enough disk space or memory"

Answer (score 0):

- Check the [LastTimeDate] column in the Access table to see if it contains any dates prior to January 1, 1753. If so, then you'll either have to fix those dates (if they are incorrect) our you'll have to tweak the column type mapping during the import to ëdit mapping for that column [LastTimeDate] with Datatype as datetime2  (instead of a datetime column) in the SQL Server table column mapping.
- Also another thing i had come across during a DB migration from Access to SQL is if the date Column was having a wrong format example :Instead of date value it was '00:00:00' so i checked through the entire Access DB for that Column containing Date values if the value was just '00:00:00' and replaced it with blank. and then migrated the DB from access to SQL . 
  Successful migration . It did work. try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your table by the date field from the oldest to newest by date.